# Building a basic calculator

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am currently learning how to code and I am having some difficulties with jQuery. I tried to do this calculator as a project through the course I am doing and I came across a bump. I don't know how to fix my code: one problem is that the operations are not working properly, nor the numbers. I tried following a tutorial, and decided to use different buttons to play around with it, but I am not getting the desired outcome. The numbers should display on the total section and the operators should give mathematical results.

You can see my full code for html, jQuery, and javascript here
http://codepen.io/IrvingG/pen/adRrvW

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var testNumLength = function(number) {
if (number.length > 9) {
  totaldiv.text(number.substr(number.length - 9, 9));
  if (number.length > 15) {
    number = "";
    totaldiv.text("Err");
  }
}
};
var number = "";
var newnumber = "";
var operator = "";
var totaldiv = $("#results");
totaldiv.text("0");

$(".numbers button").not("#operators, #equals, #clear").click(function() {
   number += this.html();
   totaldiv.text(number);
   testNumLength.text(number);
  });
 $("#operators").click(function() {
   operator += this.html();
   newnumber = number;
   number = "";
   totaldiv.text("0");
  });

 $("#clear, #clear1").click(function() {
   number = "";
   totaldiv.text("0");
   if ($(this).attr("id") === "#clear") {
     newnumber = ";"
   }
 });

 $("#equals").click(function(){
   if (operator === "+"){
     number = (parseInt(number, 10) + parseInt(number, 10).toString(10));
   } else if (operator === "-"){
   number = (parseInt(number, 10) - parseInt(number, 10).toString(10));
} else if (operator === "/"){
  number = (parseInt(number, 10) / parseInt(number, 10).toString(10));
} else if (operator === "*"){
  number = (parseInt(number, 10) * parseInt(number, 10).toString(10));
} 

totaldiv.text(number);
testNumLength(number);
number="";
newnumber="";
});
```

});

Comment: Right after this line: number += this.html(); add console.log(typeof number); and look at the result. Are you actually getting numbers, or just strings?

Comment: Thank you! I will try this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code [Calculator](http://jsbin.com/kopuye/edit?html,js,output)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var testNumLength = function(number) {
if (number.length > 9) {
  totaldiv.text(number.substr(number.length - 9, 9));
  if (number.length > 15) {
    number = "";
    totaldiv.text("Err");
  }
}
};
 var result;
var number = "";
var newnumber = ""; 
var operator = "";
var totaldiv = $("#results");
totaldiv.text("0");

$(".numbers button").not(".operator,#equals  ,#clear").click(function() {
   number += $(this).html();

   totaldiv.text(number);
   testNumLength(number);

  });
 $(".operator").click(function() { 
   operator = $(this).html();

   newnumber = number;
   number = "";
   totaldiv.text("0");

  });

 $("#clear, #clear1").click(function() {
   number = "";
   totaldiv.text("0");
   if ($(this).attr("id") === "#clear") {
     newnumber = ";";
   }
 });

 $("#equals").click(function(){ 
   if (operator === "+"){
     result=parseInt(newnumber, 10) + parseInt(number, 10);
     number = result.toString(10); 

   } else if (operator === "-"){
  result=parseInt(newnumber, 10) -  parseInt(number, 10);

     number = result.toString(10);
} else if (operator === "/"){
  result=parseInt(newnumber, 10) / parseInt(number, 10);
     number = result.toString(10);
} else if (operator === "*"){
result=parseInt(newnumber, 10) * parseInt(number, 10);
     number = result.toString(10);
} 

totaldiv.text(number);
testNumLength(number);
number="";
newnumber="";
});
});
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I was looking through the code to see what was different, this helped a lot.